# How can I remove 25% of the money gained using VaultAPI?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

When a player has a setting on I want to remove 25% of their new income. How should I do this? My first thought is to use an event that triggers when a player gains money. Is there an event for this? If so, what would be the best way to remove the money?

Comment: This is not possible via basic vault. You can use [VaultEvents](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/72930/) and check [VaultAPI](https://github.com/MilkBowl/VaultAPI). Also, actually your question is off-topic for SO as need more focus

Answer (score 1):

Thic code will:

1. Get new user balance
2. Get modified amount
3. Remove that 25 of modified amount from new balance

You need to put that in your Bukkit Listener class, and register it in onEnable void
I think you can find it on internet, if not, write back.

```java
    @EventHandler
    public void onEconomyResponse(EconomyResponseEvent event) {
        if (event.getResponse().getType() == EconomyResponse.ResponseType.SUCCESS) {
            if (event.getAmount() != 0) {
                Player player = Bukkit.getPlayer(event.getAccountName());
                if (player != null) {
                    // Player's vault balance has changed
                    double newBalance = economy.getBalance(player);
                    // Then you write down value that is modified
                    double amountModified = event.getResponse().getAmount();
                    // remove 25% of amountModified from player
                    economy.withdrawPlayer(player, amountModified * 0.25);
     
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code will remove that 25% of gotten amount for a player.
I hope i helped you.
Next time, check JavaDocs http://milkbowl.github.io/VaultAPI/ .